useNavigate doesn't work after an API call
Here's my code:

export default function SignUp() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({ id: null, firstName: '', lastName: '', email: '', password: '' });
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState('')
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const CLIENT_URL = 'http://localhost:8080';

    const isNotValid = user.firstName === '' || user.lastName === '' || user.email === '' || user.password === '';

    // Handle change in form fields
    const handleChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setUser({ ...user, [name]: value })
    }

    // Handle submit event on form
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setIsLoading(true);
        setError('');

        try {
            // Validate form fields
            if (isNotValid) {
                throw new Error('All fields are required');
            }

            const response = await fetch(`${CLIENT_URL}/sign-up`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    firstName: user.firstName,
                    lastName: user.lastName,
                    email: user.email,
                    password: user.password
                }),
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Failed to sign up user');
            }

            // Process response data if needed
            const responseData = await response.json();

            // Navigate to overview page on successful sign up
            navigate('/overview');
        }
        catch (error) {
            setError(error.message);
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    }

The API call works as intended, but the page is not being redirected.
I did this before in a previous project and it works, but now it doesn't. Really confused and would like some help.
Is it something with the code? Or is it due to another error such as different versions of react-router-dom and such?

Is the url changing, but the page contents does not? If so, you may be missing a <Route> that matches /overview

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const MyComponent = () => {
const navigate = useNavigate();
const fetchDataAndNavigate = async () => {
    try {
        const data = await fetchMyApi();
        // Process data
        navigate('/next-page');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    fetchDataAndNavigate();
}, []); // Empty dependency array to run only once on mount

return (
    <div>
        {/* Component content */}
    </div>
);

};

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
